# Typescript function as argument - infer output type using inputted arguments

Tags: typescript

I have a hook that takes in a function as an argument, and returns another function. The output function has identical arguments to the inputted function. Only the return type differs.

```js
type InputFn = (...args: any[]) => Promise<string>
type OutputFn<TInput> = (args: Parameters<TInput>) => void

useDemo<TInput extends InputFn>(input: TInput): OutputFn {
   const output = useCallback((...args) => {
     input(args).then(str => doSomeStuff())
   }, 
   [])

   return output
}
```

I would like the output to be typed based on the input. e.g.

```
  const output = useDemo((a: string, b: number) => Promise.resolve(''))
  // Output Type: (a: string, b: number) => void
```

How can I achieve this? I currently only get any[] type and a lot of errors.

Answer (score 1):

You're right to use the [`Parameters` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype), but you want to use it in the return type declaration referring to the generic type parameter `TInput`, rather than outside it as a type declaration:

```typescript
function useDemo<TInput extends InputFn>(input: TInput): (...params: Parameters<TInput>) => void {
    return function(...args: Parameters<TInput>): void {
        input().then(str => { /*...*/ }); // Really need a `catch` on this! :-)
    };
}
```

Then for example:

```
const output1 = useDemo((x: string, y: number) => Promise.resolve(""));
//    ^−−− type is `(x: string, y: number) => void`
const output2 = useDemo((x: string) => Promise.resolve(""));
//    ^−−− type is `(x: string) => void`
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdmArsAYnKBeKAKAdPgQwCcBzAZwC4oC4QBtAXQEpMA+KABSIHsBbASzIQAPGWBF+cEqwDcAKDkAzRHADGwft3SIhAEQi9uwgCrwkwKBAAewCHAAmZWAmRpW2SeaqmXwJlTx8MGICXkpOEN4IWyIyEzNkVhYMdgA3bn57KABvOSh8qCJoxCJ0ZTUNLUDcYnIqDkjoiFj43ySqdMycvILez2RsJlxgAAs7bDEiNhyoAHoAKnxcedmoAF8mGTnVgCUIAgAbA5AoOAgILIIoAANVAmBVEeuoLShRwQBCKAoAWiYe-JreRrBSqLRiF7IcwARkwUB0EH0hmw2CsVEmkhIABooCAqHBELwAEbNZLsLh8QQQXBFMjcA6pCDYABEzKYmzks1WBQAegB+ORguAQ7hQ5AAJjhCKR3BRaKgGKkZM4PAEQhpEDpDKZrPZ8i5vX5QA)

Or if you want to declare it separately, you can do that, but it has to be a generic type so you can pass in the resolved type of the generic argument to `useDemo`:

```typescript
type InputFn = (...args: any[]) => Promise<string>;
type OutputFn<TInput extends InputFn> = (...params: Parameters<TInput>) => void;

function useDemo<TInput extends InputFn>(input: TInput): OutputFn<TInput> {
    return function(...args: Parameters<TInput>): void {
        input().then(str => { /*...*/ }); // Really need a `catch` on this! :-)
    };
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)